# Android findPreference() broken

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I have the following preference layout:

**xml/preferences.xml:**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:key="screen_pref">

    <!-- Populate with paid preferences -->
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Advanced" android:key="cat_pref_mods">

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <!-- Populate with debugging preferences -->
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Dbg." android:key="cat_pref_dbg">

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The first category (with key "cat_pref_mods") get populated as expected by the following code:

```
PreferenceCategory  mPreferenceCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("cat_pref_mods");
PreferenceScreen parentScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("screen_pref");
// Add category now
parentScreen.addPreference(mPreferenceCategory);
```

However, when populating the second category similarly:

```
PreferenceCategory  mPreferenceCategory = (PreferenceCategory) findPreference("cat_pref_dbg");
PreferenceScreen parentScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference("screen_pref");
// Add category now
parentScreen.addPreference(mPreferenceCategory);
```

The two category headers defined in preferences.xml, appear immediately one 
under each other and the actual preferences are concatenated afterwards.

Why doesn't category with key "cat_pref_mods" along with its entries appear 
entirely before category "cat_pref_dbg"?

While debugging the parent screen seems to be empty (""), even though is previously initialized:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

If only one category is created, the items appear as expected. When creating two, the category headers are placed immediately one under another, but the entries appear as expected afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the categories, as well as the preferences have to be added in sequence (programmatically, as objects), something along the lines of:

```
private void addPreferences() {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    PreferenceScreen parentScreen = (PreferenceScreen) findPreference(KEY_PREF_SCREEN);

    PreferenceCategory catOne= new PreferenceCategory(this);
    catOne.setTitle("Cat. #1");
    parentScreen.addPreference(catOne);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_one);

    PreferenceCategory catTwo = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    catTwo .setTitle("Cat. #2");
    parentScreen.addPreference(catTwo);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_two);
}
```